# Do pointer types wrap around their maximum value?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Consider a pointer `char* p` that is not `nullptr`, and the loop

```
while(++p);
```

Is the behaviour well defined or undefined? In other words, will the pointer eventually become 0 when reaching the maximum allocable memory (probably 2^32 or 2^64) or this is just UB?

[std::numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) is (as expected) not specialized for pointer types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: by spec, it is undefined behavior. Performing any pointer arithmetic that leads to unallocated memory more than one address past an allocated item (see the [One Past the End](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/iterators.html) chapter in the GCC docs for the significance of this) is undefined behavior.

---

To see why, let us look at the standard:

Sec 3.7.4.3.2 in the C++11 standard enumerates over all "safely-derived pointer" types. Most items in sec 3.7.4.3.2 of the standard describe ways to obtain references to objects legally. Assuming a pointer refers to allocated memory, 3.7.4.3.2 simply states:

> A pointer value is a *safely-derived pointer* to a dynamic object only if it has an object pointer type and it is one of the following:
>
> - the result of well-defined pointer arithmetic (5.7) using a safely-derived pointer value;

Sec 5.7.4 states:

> For the purposes of these operators, **a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type**.

Finally, sec 5.7.5:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: well `unsigned int` does not overflow, it wraps around modulo max_size

Comment: @vsoftco: Right, unsigned integer types don't overflow -- which makes it pretty difficult to define what would happen if they did. 8-)}

Comment: You're absolutely right. In fact a pointer is more of an `unsigned` than an `int`, which is why first paragraph and @Mike Robinson's answers are inaccurate. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: @EyasSH that's why I asked the question. A pointer usually stores the same values as a `size_t`.

Comment: @EyasSH: Pointers are neither signed nor unsigned, and there's no basis in the standard for saying that they're more similar to unsigned integers than to signed integers.

Comment: It should still be 'undefined' or 'unspecified' behavior. Let me  look up the exact relevant parts.

Comment: @EyasSH: It's undefined behavior -- but the only relevant bounds are those of the array object into which the pointer points. (A single object is treated as a one-element array for purposes of pointer arithmetic.) You could probably delete everything up to and including the word "Additionally".

Comment: @KeithThompson are you saying that you get UB because you increment the pointer past the array/allocated memory boundary? Even if you don't dereference it?

Comment: What's the significance of 'after unallocated memory'?  Is it a typo for 'after allocated memory', or are you trying to describe something else?

Comment: @vsoftco: Yes, that's exactly what the standard says in the excerpt quoted in the answer.

Comment: @vsoftco: see updated answer for detail. I also include a link to GCC's "one past the end" doc to explain the significance.

Comment: @EyasSH thanks, your answer now seems to nail it! I was aware of the one-past-the-end stuff (since otherwise using `[a,b)` ranges would have been a pain), however I had the impression that you enter UB only when trying to dereference.

Comment: Just 5.7.5 should've been sufficient. It's pretty clear.

Comment: @Barry the thing that throws me off a bit is the link between the pointer and the array/memory. In particular, the standard doesn't say what happens with a pointer that is un-initialized, does it?

Comment: @Barry yes, I guess that's true. But what if `char* p = (char*)0xAABB10E` ? In this way you initialize the pointer, but of course have no idea what's at that memory location, and most certainly don't own it.

Comment: @Barry: 5.7.4 is quite necessary to explain that this behavior is not exclusive to arrays. Including 3.7.4.3.2 is a weaker argument.

Comment: @EyasSH I think 5.7.4 answers my last question above.

Answer (score 2):

From a specification point of view: it's UB.

From a *what-will-it-do* point of view, yes, it will eventually wrap around to zero in most environments, especially for plain C. It may take a century or so on a 64-bit system.